# Extract a number from a string that occurs between a letter and tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a MySQL text field in an online diary I have, which sometimes contain text like `D<num> <tag>`, for example `D109 MU`.

Those references can appear in any part of the field - so might be:

```
D109 MU, worked from home today
Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym in the evening for the 9th time this month.
```

I have worked out an SQL query to pull out the references which include the `D<num> <tag>` content, via this - so for example, by going to URL:

> example.com/tidy.php?v1=7346&v2=90000&tag=MU

The querystring data is used to get the data out of the field:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

if (!empty($_GET['v1'])) {
    $v1 = $purifier->purify($_GET['v1']);
}

if (!empty($_GET['v2'])) {
    $v2 = $purifier->purify($_GET['v2']);
}

if (!empty($_GET['tag'])) {
    $tag = $purifier->purify($_GET['tag']);
}

$sql = "select id, post_date, post_content from tbl_log_days where id between :v1 and :v2 and post_content REGEXP :exp ";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':v1', $v1);
$stmt->bindParam(':v2', $v2);
$stmt->bindValue(":exp" , "D[0-9]+ $tag", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

That works okay - so I get the relevant `post_content` entries.

However, I am struggling working out the syntax to pull out only the number of the D part of the content.

I have got this far:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $dt = $row['post_date'];
    $pc = $row['post_content'];

    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $pc, $matches);
    $number = implode(' ', $matches[0]);

    echo "$number <hr>";

}
```

The trouble with that is often the content includes multiple numbers, but I only want to get the number that appears between the D and the `tag` value. So for D109 MU, I'd want to extract 109, and for the 2nd example, I'd want to extract 110 from D110 MU, but ignore the number 9 that appears later in that same field.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: is the tag always MU or does it have a specific type?

Comment: `preg_match_all('/D(\d+)\sMU/', $str, $matches)` should do it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no answers as comments please

Comment: @mickmackusa - sorry I get bored of answering Regex questions all the time.  Plus I am leaving soon and wouldn't have the time to properly explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specific if the `MU` is a reliable string to match, so I'm leaving that out.  Match the `D`, restart the fullstring match with `\K`, then match 1 or more digits.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lp5To))  ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eaEANz/1))

```
$string = 'D109 MU, worked from home today
Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym in the     evening for the 9th time this month.';

var_export(preg_match_all('~D\K\d+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '109',
  1 => '110',
)
```

---

Extension: If you need to increase the pattern accuracy by adding the known `tag` value, you can add the `$tag` variable to the pattern as a lookahead.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aperC))

```
$tag = "MU";
$string = 'D109 MU, worked from home today
Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym in the     evening for the 9th time this month.';

var_export(preg_match_all("~D\K\d+(?= $tag)~", $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail');
```

---

Furthermore, if your strings only contain one qualifying `<num>`, then `preg_match()` will suffice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NLBBZ))

```
$tag = "MU";
$strings = [
    'D109 MU, worked from home today',
    'Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym in the     evening for the 9th time this month.'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo "\n---\n" , preg_match("~D\K\d+(?= $tag)~", $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail';
}
```

Output:

```
---
109
---
110
```

Comment: `\K` is interesting, I've never seen it used before, so I will have to do some looking into it.  Nice answer!

Comment: Oh really, I use it ALL the time when answering because it often avoids using a capture group. (capture groups increase the step count for those who care)  Please delete your comments under the question.

Comment: Yea, I've used `\Z` in code, which no one uses.  But never `\K`  `\Z` matches the end of the string .  I used it as part of an HTML lexer/parser template engine I am working on.  [\Z on Regx101](https://regex101.com/r/KbyoXu/1) basically its a substitute for `feof`

Comment: just a minor problem though, it doesn't care about the tag being there. It will catch `12` in `Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym, took the bus D12 and  in the evening for the 9th time this month.`

Comment: How did I learn the very best regex tricks? I watched [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) and [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) answer questions.  (Of course, there are some other great regex talents that have showed me some things too, but I won't list them all.)  If I saw something for the first time, I researched.

Comment: @Cemal Of course we can invent fringe cases to break my pattern.  The question is not clear about the `MU` substring.  If it needs to be followed by a space and 1 or more uppercase letters, I can write that too.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to `invent` anything. Your regex is better than mine, I'm simply trying to make it tailored to the problem. Regardless of the fact that OP was being unclear about `tag`'s format, it should at least try to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tag is always  `MU`.

```
$re = '/D(\d*) MU/'; //or $re = '/D(\d+) MU/';
//if the tag is not always MU, but 2 upcase characters, use the $re below
//$re = '/D(\d*) [A-Z]{2}/';  //or     //$re = '/D(\d+) [A-Z]{2}/';

$str = 'D109 MU, worked from home today
Walked the dog, later took the kids to swimming. D110 MU. Went to the gym in the     evening for the 9th time this month.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

`$matches` will contain the numbers you need. The output is as below

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
                string(7) "D109 MU"
            [1]=>
                string(3) "109"
        }
    [1]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
                string(7) "D110 MU"
            [1]=>
                string(3) "110"
        }
}
```

Comment: You only need `m` flag if you use the `^` and `$` so they match at the beginning and end of each line, instead of the string.

Comment: Yes, you're right. regex101 added it. Edited and removed it.

Comment: Oh and I would use `\d+` not the `*`  one or more, verses none or more.  As this is what they want to capture there is no point capturing none.

Comment: regex101 - doesn't properly represent `preg_match_all` unfortunately.  Otherwise its one of the best Regex sites that I know of.

Comment: agreed about regex101, however they have a fabulous regex debugger :D